# Add Scroll Bar with Individual column searching (select inputs) in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a table with 17 columns and I want to add scroll (horizontal and vertical) bar but the problem is if I will add this code below:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "scrollY": 200,
  "scrollX": true
});
```

I get this message:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
>   For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {

      var select = $('<select data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control" ><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
          .on( 'change', function () {
              var val = $(this).val();

              table.column( i )
                  .search( val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false )
                  .draw();
          } );

      table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
          select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
      } );
  } );

  $('#example').dataTable({
    "scrollY": 200,
    "scrollX": true
    });


} );
```

Any help/suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you're initialised the table twice. First with no options, `var table = $('#example').DataTable();`, then again with `$('#example').dataTable({...}`. If you replace that first initialisation with the second, you should be good.

Cheers,

Colin

Comment: Cheers, but the problem is I can not do Individual column searching

Comment: I've created a fiddle doing what I suggested, with the two merged - see http://live.datatables.net/zinaxeli/1/edit.